# In Excel, need to find duplicate value in column 1 and compare to see if values in column 2 also match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two columns in Excel.

Each cell in column 1 contains a name while each cell in column 2 contains a category.

For every instance of a value in column 1, I want to look at the corresponding value in column 2 and see if they match. If they don't match, then I want to flag the differences.

For example:

```
Name        Category
Best Buy    Electronics
Best Buy    Electronics
Best Buy    Home Furnishings
Home Depot  Home Improvement
Home Depot  Home Improvement
```

Should return:

```
Name        Category
Best Buy    Electronics
Best Buy    Home Furnishings
```

What would such a function look like? I'm stumped on how to have it search all of column 1, excluding the cell in column 1 that we are looking to match and then how to include the comparison of multiple matches within column 1.

Any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Not sure what the requirements are and the relation from input to output.
In addition, if you have not had a chance to write code or formulas, then please do that first and ask a specific question. SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Looks like you could solve this just using the remove duplicates function in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Pivot table. Select both columns, create a pivot table of those and again use both columns as pivot row fields. You need to apply the table layout then to see it in the way you need it.